# How to use div for background in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, particles.js

Hi I am trying to build a website, and I am trying to use particles.js as my background and display the content in overlaying manner. However, it is displaying it on top of the page instead of the background. When I set its position as absolute, its changes the format of my website. How can I set that div as the background?

here how it changes the format of the website , when I set it as absolute

[image]

I have my background div id set as **particles-js**
here is my code for base.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

{% load static %}
{% static 'style.css' %}
{% static 'particles.json' %}

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>

<body>

{% include 'snippets/base_css.html' %}
{% include 'snippets/header.html' %}



<!-- Body -->
<style type="text/css">
    .main{
        min-height: 100vh;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
<div class="main">
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
      
    <script>
        particlesJS.load('particles-js', "{% static 'particles.json' %}", function(){
            console.log('particles.json loaded...');
        });
    </script>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
</div>
<!-- End Body -->

{% include 'snippets/footer.html' %}

</body>


</html>
```

this is my home.html:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<style type="text/css">

    @media (max-width: 768px) { 
        .right-column{
            margin-left: 0px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) { 
        .right-column{
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    }

    .blog-post-container{
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .create-post-bar{
        background-color: #fff;
        margin-bottom:20px;
    }

    .left-column{
        padding:0px;
    }

    .right-column{
        padding:0px;
    }
    .lead{
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #000220;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>



<!-- main content -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        

        <!-- blog feed -->
        <div class="left-column col-lg-7 offset-lg-1">

            <!-- Top 'create post' bar -->
            <div class="d-lg-none mb-3">
                <div class="card m-auto d-flex flex-column p-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid d-block m-auto pb-2" src="{% static 'covalent.png' %}" width="72" height="72">
                    <p class="m-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog:create' %}">Create post</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end Top 'create post' bar -->

            <!-- Blog posts-->
            {% if blog_posts %}
                {% for post in blog_posts %}
                    <div class="blog-post-container">
                        {% include 'blog/snippets/blog_post_snippet.html' with blog_post=post %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <div class="blog-post-container">
                    {% include 'blog/snippets/blog_post_snippet.html' with query=query %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- End Blog posts-->

        <!-- Pagination -->
        {% include 'blog/snippets/blog_post_pagination.html' with blog_posts=blog_posts %}

        </div>
        <!-- end blog feed -->


        <!-- Right 'create post' column  -->
        <div class="right-column col-lg-3 d-lg-flex d-none flex-column">

            <div class="card create-post-bar d-flex flex-column p-3">
                <img class="img-fluid d-block m-auto pb-2" src="{% static 'covalent.png' %}" width="72" height="72">
                <p class="lead">Welcome to the HUB</p>
                <p class="m-auto"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'blog:create' %}">Create post</a></p>
            </div>
        
        </div>
        <!-- end Right 'create post' column  -->



    </div>
</div>





{% endblock content %}
```

and this is my style.css

```
    <style type="text/css">


    body{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #000220;

    }
    #particles-js{
         height: 100% ;

 
        }


</style>
```

Comment: apply a negative `z-index` like `z-index: -1;` to that particular div.

Comment: An element with `position: absolute;` (or any position other than `static`) always positions itself with respect the closest non-static parent. So, since you have your `<div>` directly inside the `<body>`, it positions itself with respect to body (which is `relative` positioned by default). Try enclosing your background and overlay inside another `<section>` with `position: relative;` (used section just to make it semantically correct html) and you can give it `height` and `width` of `100vh` and `100vw` to further make it full screen banner effect (optional).

Comment: @deekeh, it does what I want but changes the format of the webpage. I just want that div to be displayed in the background without changing the places of my content

Comment: @tacoshy it just puts the div into the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this but i am not sure if this works for you.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#background-div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(#f7f4eb, #ded9cc);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-div">
  <!--background-content-->
</div>
<div class='container'>
  your other contents
</div>
```

Comment: please give a sufficient explanation to your answer. `code only` answers are considered low quality.

Comment: ok I will try, I am new to stack overflow

Comment: When I try this method, it doesn't affect the format, but it displays the div  over the content instead of the background

Comment: it did! Thank you!